# Serialize object to XmlDocument

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, xmldocument

In order to return useful information in `SoapException.Detail` for an asmx web service, I took an idea from WCF and created a fault class to contain said useful information.  That fault object is then serialised to the required `XmlNode` of a thrown `SoapException`.

I'm wondering whether I have the best code to create the `XmlDocument` - here is my take on it:

```
var xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    serializer.Serialize(stream, theObjectContainingUsefulInformation);
    stream.Flush();
    stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

    xmlDocument.Load(stream);
}
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

**UPDATE:** I actually ended up doing the following, because unless you wrap the XML in a `<detail>` xml element, you get a `SoapHeaderException` at the client end:

```
var serialiseToDocument = new XmlDocument();
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    serializer.Serialize(stream, e.ExceptionContext);
    stream.Flush();
    stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

    serialiseToDocument.Load(stream);
}

// Remove the xml declaration
serialiseToDocument.RemoveChild(serialiseToDocument.FirstChild);

// Memorise the node we want
var serialisedNode = serialiseToDocument.FirstChild;

// and wrap it in a <detail> element
var rootNode = serialiseToDocument.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "detail", "");
rootNode.AppendChild(serialisedNode);
```

**UPDATE 2:** Given John Saunders excellent answer, I've now started using the following:

```
private static void SerialiseFaultDetail()
{
    var fault = new ServiceFault
                    {
                        Message = "Exception occurred",
                        ErrorCode = 1010
                    };

    // Serialise to the XML document
    var detailDocument = new XmlDocument();
    var nav = detailDocument.CreateNavigator();

    if (nav != null)
    {
        using (XmlWriter writer = nav.AppendChild())
        {
            var ser = new XmlSerializer(fault.GetType());
            ser.Serialize(writer, fault);
        }
    }

    // Memorise and remove the element we want
    XmlNode infoNode = detailDocument.FirstChild;
    detailDocument.RemoveChild(infoNode);

    // Move into a root <detail> element
    var rootNode = detailDocument.AppendChild(detailDocument.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "detail", ""));
    rootNode.AppendChild(infoNode);

    Console.WriteLine(detailDocument.OuterXml);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: overall it looks good to me, though I think I'd use strongly typed objects rather than vars in this case. Also, I don't know that the `stream.Seak(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)` is really necessary.

Comment: I updated my post code for the detail element.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**EDIT: Creates output inside of detail element**

```
public class MyFault
{
    public int ErrorCode { get; set; }
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
}

public static XmlDocument SerializeFault()
{
    var fault = new MyFault
                    {
                        ErrorCode = 1,
                        ErrorMessage = "This is an error"
                    };

    var faultDocument = new XmlDocument();
    var nav = faultDocument.CreateNavigator();
    using (var writer = nav.AppendChild())
    {
        var ser = new XmlSerializer(fault.GetType());
        ser.Serialize(writer, fault);
    }

    var detailDocument = new XmlDocument();
    var detailElement = detailDocument.CreateElement(
        "exc", 
        SoapException.DetailElementName.Name,
        SoapException.DetailElementName.Namespace);
    detailDocument.AppendChild(detailElement);
    detailElement.AppendChild(
        detailDocument.ImportNode(
            faultDocument.DocumentElement, true));
    return detailDocument;
}
```

Comment: +1 for being a really neat solution.  However, given that I need to wrap the serialised object's XML in a root "<detail>" element, what's the best approach?  I tried creating a node, then using the new node's navigator but got an InvalidOperationException with "WriteStartDocument cannot be called on writers created with ConformanceLevel.Fragment."

Comment: Ahh, now I understand.  Using the return value of ImportNode for the AppendChild call was the link in the chain I was missing.  I really hate these messy XML classes in .net, I must say.  Thanks for your help.