# Convert a generic collection to a XML in C#

Tags: c#, xml, generics, reflection

I want to write a generic method that returns a XML once a collection of type T is passed. I tried below code, but doesn't work as expected. Any advise on enhancing this to include element attributes is highly appreciated. Thanks

```
public XElement GetXElements<T>(IEnumerable<T> colelction,string parentNodeName) where T : class
{            
    XElement xml = new XElement(typeof(T).GetType().Name);
    foreach(var x in typeof(T).GetProperties())
    {
        var name = x.Name;
        var value = typeof(T).GetProperty(x.Name).GetValue(x);
        xml.Add(new XElement(name,value));
    }         
    return xml;
}
```

For example, if I send a collection like below to above method,

```
        var col = new List<Employee>()
        {
            new Employee
            {
                FirstName = "John",
                Sex= "Male"
            },
            new Employee
            {
                FirstName = "Lisa",
                Sex= "Female"
            },
        };
```

and invoke the method as `GetXElements<Employee>(col,"Employees")`I am expecting to get a XML like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Employees>
  <Employee>
     <FirstName>John</FirstName>
     <Sex>Male</Sex>
  </Employee>
  <Employee>
     <FirstName>Lisa</FirstName>
     <Sex>Female</Sex>
  </Employee>
<Employees>
```

Comment: Your method only has one parameter - why are you passing two arguments?

Comment: Why dont you use serialization?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/781442/serialize-object-to-xmldocument

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you've understood what the argument to `PropertyInfo.GetValue` is meant to be - it's meant to be the *target* of the property fetch, whereas you're passing in the `PropertyInfo` itself.

Additionally, your method only has one parameter, whereas you're trying to pass in two arguments. I think you want something like this:

```
public static XElement GetXElements<T>(IEnumerable<T> collection, string wrapperName)
    where T : class
{
    return new XElement(wrapperName, collection.Select(GetXElement));
}

private static XElement GetXElement<T>(T item)
{
    return new XElement(typeof(T).Name,
        typeof(T).GetProperties()
                 .Select(prop => new XElement(prop.Name, prop.GetValue(item, null));
}
```

That gives the result you're looking for. Note that you don't need to specify the type argument when calling `GetXElement`, as type inference will do the right thing:

```
XElement element = GetXElements(col,"Employees");
```